# ANDROID O Notification does not work.

Tags: android, mobile

using

```js
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.view.View;
```

created 2nd activity called secoundactivity 
on 1st Activity created button and calling following method

```
        String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.network_service)
                    .setContentTitle("My notification")
                    .setContentText("Hello World!")
            .setChannel(CHANNEL_ID);

                    //.setchannelid(CHANNEL_ID);

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, secondactivity.class);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(secondactivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

and using  
  Compile SDK Version : API 26: Android 8.0 (O) 
  Build Tool : 26.0.1

Please Help as i am just new

Comment: What do you mean with does not work?Is it crashing?

Comment: Also, it is not necessary to post the imports here

Comment: its not showing anything .. can you explain me what you mean imports , already post on top what i am importing, program does not give any error. anything mean when i click button that should show notification but that does not i debug program and its going to click event reading all code and then do not display any notification

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Things you need to know

.1 Notification
.2 Notification.Builder
.3 NotificationCompat.Builder

following Solution work for me.

**Created 2 Activity**

.1 "MainActivity" 
.2 "SecondClass"  (please ignore the name conv)

Created one **button** in MainActivity and calling method getSendNotification(View vm)

```
public void getSendNotification(View vm) {
    String id = "1";
    CharSequence name = "my Channel";
    String description = "Description";
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
    NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, name,importance);
    mChannel.setDescription(description);
    mChannel.enableLights(true);
    mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
    mChannel.enableVibration(true);
    mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);


    Notification.Builder  mBuilder
    = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.preferences_desktop_notification_bell)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("Text")
            .setChannelId(id);

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, SecondClass.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(SecondClass.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SecondClass">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="second_filter" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>
```

**but Notification.Builder (i have message is deprecated , mean i should not use it )**

but with **NotificationCompat.Builder**

i am still receiving error message

**failed to post notification on Channel "null"**  


**only working with Notification.Builder**

Comment: If you're trying to add more details to your question, you should edit your question, not add an answer. And if you accept your own answer, nobody else will try to answer your question.

Comment: Does it work with `Notification.Builder`? Even if it's deprecated, you can still use it. But if you're using `NotificationCompat.Builder`, are you using `NotificationManagerCompat` also?

Answer (score 5):

You're setting the channel in the notification, but you need to create the channel through `NotificationManager` first.

So, first create the channel like this.

```
val manager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
// Creating a channel - required for O's notifications.
val channel = NotificationChannel("my_channel_01",
         "Channel human readable title",
         NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
manager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
```

And then, you can use the channel's id when building your notification.

```
// Building the notification.
val builder = Notification.Builder(context, channel.id)
// Using the channel's id in the builder.
builder.setChannelId(channel.id)
```

And finally, you can post your notification.

```
// Posting the notification.
manager.notify(notificationId, builder.build())
```

Comment: ok i have tried this code , and same thing notification does not appear.

Comment: here is update created NEW DEVICE pixel XL , now when i click on button, following error came "failed to post notification on channel null" some where i read it say i must have google play store update, but i do not know how to...

Comment: You shouldn't need anything with Google Play for this, it's just a local notification. It sounds like your Channel isn't set up correctly. Make sure you create the Channel, and use it's Id.

Comment: code already posted , and i believe there is no error in code. do you have anything else to suggest

Comment: Yes, you're not creating a Channel in that code, you're just passing a String as the id. Look at how in my example I'm creating a Channel and adding it to the NotificationManager. Make sure you're actually doing that step. Then later, I'm able to set the Channel's Id by with that Channel.

Comment: Kudos for using Kotlin.  It makes things clearer for beginners.